# Constrain Kotlin generic to not null in one case

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a generic type (`T: Any?`) that I need constrained in one situation never to be `null`:

```
class Repository<T> { // T may be a non-null or nullable type.
  fun getFromFoo(): T {}
  fun getFromBar(): T {} // This is never null. Can I mark it as so?
}


val repository = Repository<String>()
val fromFoo: String = repository.getFromFoo() // Returns a non-null String.
val fromBar: String = repository.getFromBar() // How do I make this work?


val repository = Repository<String?>()
val fromFoo: String? = repository.getFromFoo() // Returns a nullable String.
val fromBar: String = repository.getFromBar() // How do I make this return a non-null String?
```

While I would ideally refactor these into separate types (like `FooRepository` and `BarRepository`), is there any way to get this type constraint functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is the type `T & Any` — an intersection of generic `T` and `Any`. It represents such subtype of `T` that can never contain nulls.

Unfortunately the intersection types and this intersection in particular currently are non-denotable in Kotlin, meaning that you can't declare a return type of a function to be non-nullable subtype of `T`.

Comment: Actually, there is a syntax for type intersection in Kotlin: `fun <S> getFromBar(): S where S : T, S : Any { ... }`

But in this particular case it wouldn't help, because type intersection with type parameter is not allowed at all

Comment: In Kotlin 1.7.10 this is working fine (no idea when this was actually introduced).

Comment: This limited form of intersection types - definitely non-nullable types - were introduced in Kotlin 1.7: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew17.html#stable-definitely-non-nullable-types

Answer (score 4):

```
class Repository<T : Any> { // T may only be a non-null type.
  fun getFromFoo(): T? {} // This may return null.
  fun getFromBar(): T {} // This is never null.
}

val repository = Repository<String>()
val fromFoo: String? = repository.getFromFoo()
val fromBar: String = repository.getFromBar()
```

Require a non-null type. You can selectively indicate nullability via `T?` vs `T` for your methods/properties.

EDIT: Revised solution based on question clarification found in the comments

My impression now is that you want one method to always return a non-null value, even if T is of a nullable type. The short answer is no, there is no way to do this.

You could however, define two generics:

```
 class Repository<T, N : T> {
  fun getFromFoo(): T {}
  fun getFromBar(): N {}
}

val repository = Repository<String?, String>()
val fromFoo: String? = repository.getFromFoo()
val fromBar: String = repository.getFromBar()
```

`<T, N : T>` is one option, but it doesn't enforce that `N` be of a non-nullable type. `<T, N : Any>` is another option, this forces `N` to be a non-nullable type, but it's not longer forced to extend `T`. Pick your poison.

This makes constructing Repository uglier but gives you the convience of it being non-null at all of the call sites.

Comment: The user of the Repository doesn't get the type safety benefit from non-null types, then. Consider Repository<String>.getFromFoo. This should return a String, but with your code, it will return a String? unfortunately!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but from the question, that looked like exactly what you specified that you wanted. `fromFoo`'s return type is nullable as desired, and `fromBar`'s is non-nullable.

Comment: If the Repository is parameterized with a non-nullable type like String, neither method should be able to return null.

Comment: Have you tried it...? Note the `T?` return type of `getFromFoo`. The return type of of `Repository<String>.getFromFoo` is `String?`.

Comment: I think I understand what you are looking for now, I've updated my answer.

Comment: ` String?` is what it should return, no need for your edit!

Comment: That's exactly what my original answer does.

Comment: @s1m0nw1 who's to say that's what it should return? @Eric Cochran says in the comments here that that isn't what he wanted. You understood the question as I did but based on his comments , I now believe he wants to be able to indicate that a certain method may NEVER return a nullable type even if `T` was of a nullable type, which isn't supported.

Comment: To me it does not make sense, your first answer is fine though - still

Comment: Basically there is a way in the language to say that a method may return `null`, even if the class was parameterized with a non-nullable type. For example, `Repository<String>` where `getFromFoo` returns `String?` and `getFromBar` returns `String`. I think the question is, is there a way to indicate that a method returns a non-nullable type, even if the class were parameterized with one - short answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this easily in Kotlin 1.7 with [definitely non-nullable types﻿](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew17.html#stable-definitely-non-nullable-types):

```
class Repository<T> { // T may be a non-null or nullable type.
    fun getFromFoo(): T { TODO() }
    fun getFromBar(): T & Any { TODO() } // This is never null.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the opposite. Assume your generic type is not nullable:

```
class Repository<T> {
  fun getFromFoo(): T? { ... }
  fun getFromBar(): T { ... }
}

val repository = Repository<String>()
val fromFoo: String? = repository.getFromFoo()
val fromBar: String = repository.getFromBar()
```

Comment: Check my comment on the other answer. It's not that easy, unfortunately.

Comment: @EricCochran please edit the question if the details in that comment are essential

Comment: @Ilya Updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You should not parametrize with nullable types. You should rather use non-null types and then make the nullability explicit where really needed:

```
class Repository<out T : Any> {
    fun getFromFoo(): T? {
        TODO()
    }

    fun getFromBar(): T {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

You say that `T` is supposed to be a non-null type (`T: Any`), and say that `getFromFoo()` might return `T?`, which works totally fine.

Comment: The OP already stated that this was not what he wanted in the comments of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring into two separate classes would be a better idea, but since you don't want that you could use two generic types:

```
class Repository<T, S: Any> {
    fun getFromFoo(): T? { /* ... */ }
    fun getFromBar(): S { /* ... */ }
}
```